# Output a map of sets of elements that are disjoint in every other list of elements from a Map of lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a map of lists, each list has integers. Output is a map of sets of elements that are disjoint in every other list of elements.

For ex:
Below is a map of lists

List 1 - 1,2,3,4,5

List 2 - 3,4,5,6,7,8

List 3 - 1,2,3,5,6,7,8

Intersection of all lists is - 3,5
output should be map of lists (excluding 3, 5)

List 1 - 1,2,4

List 2 - 4,6,7,8

List 3 - 1,2,6,7,8

I have a solution using 2 for loops but it has O(n*n) complexity. Trying to find an optimal solution. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent your different sets using hashtables. This way computing the overall intersection is *O(M)* where *M* is total number of elements across all sets.

Then, you need to compute the set difference between original sets and that computed intersection. Again, this is done really fast using hashtables *O(K*N)* where *K* is the number of elements in the overall intersection and *N* the number of sets.

The structure of the algorithm will use two non-nested for loops. The first to compute the intersection of all sets, the second to get rid of the redundant elements in all sets.

You will find a running example in C++ live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b381ec4ad34a8e6d).

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>

// Complexity: O(min(set1.size(), set2.size()))
template <typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> intersection(std::unordered_set<T> const& set1, std::unordered_set<T> const& set2) {
    if (set2.size() < set1.size()) {
        return intersection(set2, set1);
    } else {
        std::unordered_set<T> inter;
        for (auto const& el1 : set1) {
            if (std::find(set2.cbegin(), set2.cend(), el1) != set2.cend()) {
                inter.emplace(el1);
            }
        }
        return inter;
    }
}

using int_hashset = std::unordered_set<int>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int_hashset> input_sets = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
                                           {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                                           {3, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

    auto inter_set = *input_sets.cbegin();
    // Complexity: O(number of elements)
    for (auto it = input_sets.cbegin()+1; input_sets.cend() != it; ++it) {
        inter_set = intersection(inter_set, *it);
    }
    for (auto const& i : inter_set) {
        std::cout << "Elem in overall intersection: " << i << '\n';
    }

    // O(N*inter_set.size())
    for (auto& input_set : input_sets) {
        // O(inter_set.size())
        for (auto el : inter_set) {
            input_set.erase(el);
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (auto const& input_set : input_sets) {
        ++i;
        for (auto el : input_set) {
            std::cout << "Element in set " << i << ": " << el << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: This is amortized complexity. The complexity will rise if you have a lot of collisions inside your sets.*

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, would you be able to share some sample code. My confusion is around finding intersection of all sets in a single loop.

Comment: @user1879599 of course but your question is language agnostic... Which language should I use?

Comment: Prefer C# but java is fine too.

Comment: @user1879599: I only had C++ implementation at hand, but you can see for yourself. There is "two for" for the overall intersection but that still has an overall complexity of _O(total number of elements)_

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rerito